# Problem in using user defined variable in a script

Tags: shell-script, quoting

The following is a simple script, named `myscript`, that I wrote in order to run a command.

```
dcmpath='$HOME/Data'
dcmfile='IM1'
dcm2nii $dcmpath/$dcmfile
```

Unfortunately, bash does not recognize the path in front of `dcm2nii` and I cannot run the last command in the file. I would be thankful if someone could let me know what I am missing. What would be the best way of customizing the path and file name which is the argument of a command?

Comment: "bash does not recognize the path in front of `dcm2nii`" - What path? `dcm2nii` is the first thing on the line, there's nothing in front of it.

Comment: I meant `dcm2nii` does not find the file with the full path: `$dcmpath/$dcmfile` although the file really exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dcmpath="$HOME/Data"
dcmfile="IM1"
dcm2nii "$dcmpath/$dcmfile"
```

In the first line, you should use double quotes instead of single quotes.
Single quotes prevent variables like `$HOME` from being expanded; they're interpreted literally. You can see the bash manual for details: http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Quoting

It doesn't matter in the second line; both single or double quotes will work fine.

It's also good idea to (double) quote the argument in the last line, in case the variables contain a space.

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. What is the difference between defining the variable surrounded by single quotation and double quotation?

Comment: @A2009 lk has explained that in the edit.